Is $R(w\otimes x+z\otimes y)=sp\{w,z\}$ when $x, y$ are linearly independent?
Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and let $f\otimes g$ ($f,g\neq 0$) denotes the rank-one operator defined by $(f\otimes g)h=\langle h,g\rangle f$. I know that $R(f\otimes g)=sp\{f\}$.(R denotes the range.)
Is $R(w\otimes x+z\otimes y)=sp\{w,z\}$ when $x, y$ are linearly independent? I think this is essentially the promblem of whther there exists a vector $h\in H$ such that $\langle h,x\rangle=\alpha$ and $\langle h,y\rangle=\beta$ for all scalars $\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb{C}$. Could anyone give me a hint?

Just for existence, hint: use Riesz representation theorem on the span of $x$ and $y$. Alternatively, just use Gram-Schmidt to figure out the explicit form of such an $h$.

I've got the answer. Consider the linear system $\begin{cases}\lambda_1\Vert x\Vert^2+\lambda_2\langle y,x\rangle=\alpha\quad &\\\lambda_1\langle x,y\rangle+\lambda_2\Vert y\Vert^2=\beta\end{cases}$.
Since $x$ and $y$ are linearly independet, it's easy to see that the determinent of the coefficient matrix of the above system is nonzero, which means that the system is consistent.
Now set $h=\lambda_1x+\lambda_2y$, then clearly $\langle h,x\rangle=\alpha$ and $\langle h,y\rangle=\beta$.
